# Bootstrap panel unwanted right and left margins on smaller sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel, margin

I created a panel using Bootstrap and the codes below:

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="stats">
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg"></i>
        <strong>Statistics</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

But the output have a gap from left and right in panel heading.
[image]

If I remove **col-md-6**, the problem became solved. But I need to have it with 6 cols.
Please help me ...

Edit: You can take a look at this sample
http://codepen.io/mbsmt/pen/eNXmoY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have padding on the left and right because by default Bootstrap adds gutter padding to columns. The gutter width is **15px**. Here's the mixin which creates the `.col-md-` classes:

```
// Located within less/variables.less
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width: 30px;

// Located within less/mixins/grid.less
.make-md-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}
```

To remove the padding, you have two options:

1. Change the default padding to 0px. This could cause larger problems though as it will effect all your column layouts.
2. Create some custom CSS layout code targeting this specific panel such as `#stats > .panel.col-md-6`. I've supplied an example below doing this.

```css
#stats > .panel.col-md-6 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="container-fluid" id="stats">
  <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg"></i>
      <strong>Statistics</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Something ...
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what you said is the gap between the chart icon and its left side (gray box). My problem is the white space after gray heading box.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Please update your OP with your CSS if you can. This will help me understand more fully your question.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v3.3.5. to clarify my question, I've changed the snapshot image and put 2 red arrow on the gap I mentioned in the question. I hope you can get my mean.

Comment: Thank you Hynes. I changed your solution to "#stats > div.panel" to fix the problem on other sizes too. However, I think this is a bug in Bootstrap v.3.3.5 and I reported it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just wrap the panel in a div with the column classes, separate from the panel classes. It would look like this:

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="stats">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-lg"></i>
        <strong>Statistics</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Something ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple style could do the job of remove the padding like this

```
<div style="padding:0" class="panel-heading preview" >
```

But I simply can't get ride the gutter, or the space between panels.