# React-Bootstrap causing margins on left and right side

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) in my React app. It is causing margin on the left and right side. I'm using the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";

<Grid fluid>
   <Row>
      <Col xs={12} md={12}>
        <AppBar title="Title"
         iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"/>
       </Col>
   </Row>
   <Row>
       <Col xs={4} md={4}>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
       </Col>
       <Col xs={8} md={8} >
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
       </Col>
   </Row>
</Grid>
```

I'm getting the following output:
[image]

If I remove `xs and md` from `<Col>` then the issue gets fixed.

Importing twitter-bootstrap is causing this issue. If I remove the twitter-bootstrap import then the bootstrap styling doesn't work.

This issue is same as [Twitter-Bootstrap's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885148/bootstrap-panel-unwanted-right-and-left-margins-on-smaller-sizes/31885279), but I'm not able to fix it in React-Bootstrap.

Comment: Setting `Row` component `padding-left` and `padding-right` to 0 should fix the proplem

Comment: @bennygenel I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that the styles you applied works? Sometimes you need to use `!important` to override bootstrap styles

Comment: @bennygenel nothing worked. I tried `!important` but that also didn't work. I'll update the question will link to CodePen.

Comment: @bennygenel please check the updated question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tested your code with a clean react app. The previous suggestions were wrong. You need to set `Grid` components `padding-left` and `padding-right` to 0.

**UPDATE:** Just setting `Grid` is not enough. Also need to set margins to 0 of `Row` and paddings to 0 of `Col`.

You can achieve this by 3 ways.

**1. Way:** Add inline style for `Grid`, `Row` and `Col`

```
<Grid fluid style={{ paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}>
    <Row style={{ margin-left: 0, margin-right: 0 }}>
        <Col style={{ padding-left: 0, padding-right: 0 }}>
            ...
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Grid>
```

**OR**

```
const styles = {
    grid: {
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0
    },
    row: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0
    },
    col: {
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0
    }
};
<Grid fluid style={styles.grid}>
    <Row style={styles.row}>
        <Col style={styles.col}>
            ...
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Grid>
```

**2. WAY:** Add a custom class name

```
//App.css
div.noPadding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

div.noMargin {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

//App.js
import '/path/to/your/App.css';

render() {
    return (
        <Grid fluid className="noPadding">
            <Row className="noMargin">
                <Col className="noPadding">
                    ...
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

**3. WAY** You can globally change `Grid`, `Row` and `Col` components behaviour by overriding components className

```
//App.css

div.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

div.row {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px
}

div.col-lg-1,div.col-lg-10,div.col-lg-11,div.col-lg-12,div.col-lg-2,div.col-lg-3,div.col-lg-4,div.col-lg-5,div.col-lg-6,div.col-lg-7,div.col-lg-8,div.col-lg-9,
div.col-md-1,div.col-md-10,div.col-md-11,div.col-md-12,div.col-md-2,div.col-md-3,div.col-md-4,div.col-md-5,div.col-md-6,div.col-md-7,div.col-md-8,div.col-md-9,
div.col-sm-1,div.col-sm-10,div.col-sm-11,div.col-sm-12,div.col-sm-2,div.col-sm-3,div.col-sm-4,div.col-sm-5,div.col-sm-6,div.col-sm-7,div.col-sm-8,div.col-sm-9,
div.col-xs-1,div.col-xs-10,div.col-xs-11,div.col-xs-12,div.col-xs-2,div.col-xs-3,div.col-xs-4,div.col-xs-5,div.col-xs-6,div.col-xs-7,div.col-xs-8,div.col-xs-9 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that this creates a horizontal scroll. http://res.cloudinary.com/amanshu-kataria/image/upload/v1505152961/Capture2_a1eewa.png

Comment: that might be related to rows having margin left and right -15px

Comment: Setting `overflow: hidden` fixed the problem. Is this the right way to solve it?

Comment: In my opinion its not because it means that there is still content right side of the window. You should find what goes over the window width and fix that.

Comment: @AmanshuKataria actually I got it all wrong. I tested the code again and setting padding for Grid is not the way to go because then Col components creates the horizontal scroll. You should actually set padding 0 for Col components. If you set Grid's paddings to 0 and Rows margins to 0 and Cols paddings to 0 everything sits perfectly  Are you using Chrome Dev Tools to test css easily?

Comment: I tried, and it worked. Please update your answer as well.

Answer (score 7):

I used react-bootstrap with next.js. I came up with short solution:

```
<Container fluid className="p-0">
    ...
</Container>
```

Comment. bootstrap's css was imported in my _App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Another thing to add is to use
`<Row className="g-0"> ... </Row>` where `g-0` removes gutter between `Col`s.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is overkill. This really isn't that complicated. According to the official React Bootstrap documentation on [Grid](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) the **fluid** property can be applied. Here's the description for **fluid**:

*Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by this property.
Adds container-fluid class.*

Here's what I did and it works perfectly:

```
<Grid fluid={true}>
```

Answer (score 3):

Really late to the party here; I just wanted to add that in Bootstrap 4, I was able to remove the column margins by adding `fluid="true"` to the `Container` and `noGutters` to the `Row`, e.g.

```
<Grid fluid="true">
  <Row noGutters>
    <Col>
      {/* ... <contents> ... */}
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

Adding `fluid` only does not seem to be enough. Sample code is untested.

Answer (score 3):

**2021**
I faced the same issue with react bootstrap the way I solved it is by nullifying gutters. Bootstrap 5 classes work perfectly in such cases.

```
   <Container fluid className='gx-0'>
    <Row className='gx-0'>
      <Col>
        <div>Content</div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
   </Container>
```

Note that you also need to add gx-0 not only to the parent *Container*, but also to the child *Row*, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The most correct answer that worked for me is

```
<Container fluid style={{paddingLeft: '0px', paddingRight: '0px'}}>
<Row noGutters>
<COl>
//Whatever your content
</COl>
</Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I changed the row to grid. if that fails, then you need to post more code. is there any other div containers the navbar is inside?

there is a few ways to do this:

```
grid
{
margin: 0;
}
```

another way is:

```
grid
{
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @AmanshuKataria - is there any other divs the navbar is in?? can you please post the full code please?

Comment: so what is the css? do you have access to a css file for it? if so, paste the css for it