# How to extend header to the full page width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I extend my header to the full page? I have tried margin-left & right but that doesn't work.

Header.css

```
    background: green;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
} 


  .header-right {
    float: right;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }
```

Here's my app.tsx file:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header'>
  <h1>Instaride</h1>
  <div className="header-right">
    <Button> Sign In</Button>
    <Button> Contact</Button>
  </div>
</div>
);

export default Header;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your container CSS code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there could be a margin for your body element. Try setting:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in the header but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance you could post the html?

Comment: See the updated qs

Comment: For html classes the correct syntax is <div class=' className '> rather than <div className = '    ' > Not sure if this is related to the problem

Comment: This is react. React only has classNames and not class

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151515/react-bootstrap-causing-margins-on-left-and-right-side